# Is there a published list of Petrel project version numbers for older version of Petrel?

Tags: ocean

With newer versions of Petrel, the `Project.ProjectVersion` property will return a value that directly maps to the Petrel version. For example, a project saved with Petrel 2011.2 will have the `Project.ProjectVersion`value of "2011.2". However for projects created with older Petrel versions, the format is different. For example, a Petrel 2007 project might have the value 1024 and a Petrel 2005 project might be 824.

My question is, is there a published list anywhere that maps these numbers (1024 etc) to specific Petrel releases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the list of Project.Version possible values and versions of Petrel they translate to. Please note that in Petrel 2014.1 there will be a new Ocean API providing a `Project`'s `VersionInfo` structure with a full version information, including string version, major, minor version numbers etc. `Project.Version` property will be obsolete in 2014.1.

```
0        project not saved yet, or project saved by Petrel version 2.0 or earlier
522      2.1
768      3.0
778      3.1
788      3.2
798      3.3
809      2002SE
818      2003
819      2003SE
828      2004
838      2005
848      early 2007.1 alpha
1024     2007.*
1034     2008.*
20091    2009.*
20101    2010.*
20111    2011.1
20112    2011.2.*
20121    2012.1
20122    2012.2
20123    2012.3
20124    2012.4
20125    2012.5
3329     2013.1
```

The list might not be complete and I will keep it updated.

Comment: I think this list is a bit out of date now. Is there any chance you could update it please? Specifically, what values should I expect for 2013.2 - 2013.4?

Answer (score 1):

I would leave this as a comment as it does not directly answer the question, but I don't have commenting privileges yet.

Have you tried the [Schlumberger Software Support Portal](https://support.slb.com/)?

Comment: I did indeed. My question has received two views and no replies. I find Stack Overflow to be a much better place to ask questions as I'm more likely to get a reply.

Comment: Ok, I was just curious as I discovered it when trying to find an answer for you, but I could not log in to see what kind of information they had.

Comment: You can assume Evgeny's answer as the answer provided by SLB. Btw, to speed up a response from the SLB support portal, please be sure that your Ocean question is addressed to the "Global Ocean Framework" team.